# Why won't Konsole start from the icewm menu?

Tags: kde, icewm

This used to work.   My icewm menu has an item for running konsole.  In .icewm/menu the line is:

```
prog "xterm" xterm  konsole
```

Sometime, a month or so ago, without any changes to my .icewm/ files or /etc or anywhere, it stopped. Bringing up the menu and clicking 'xterm' (a misnomer, but whatever) nothing at all happens.  Previously, a Konsole window with bash prompt would appear.

I can still get konsole to run straight from any command line in another xterm, rxvt, konsole, or gnome-terminal.  There are no error messages or anything suspicious.  I'm running on Arch Linux, updated just  a few months ago, well before this mysterious loss of function.

Perhaps related, in Thunar, "open xterm here" doesn't do anything. It used to work, and as far as I recall, stopped working at the same time.

I tried using pacman to remove and reinstall konsole, and thunar, but no change.

Note that I'm not using the KDE desktop, but do use kwrite, konsole, ksnapshot and a few other KDE-based apps.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://ice-wm.org/man/icewm-menu) that should work.  Its FAQ doesn't mention a way to trace its actions, but making a script to call from the menu which shows the environment variables might give some clues.

```
prog "traces" xterm  /tmp/mytraces
```

where `/tmp/mytraces` is your script, containing something like

```
#!/bin/sh
output=/tmp/mytraces.log
date >>$output
echo "SET:" >>$output
set >>$output
echo "ENV:" >>$output
env >>$output
```

I'd look at the `PATH` variable for instance, but generally look at the environment to see that it is consistent with what I see in a normal shell.  Bear in mind that the window manager may be executed with fewer variables (and different) from your shell.